# jquery autocomplete source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

есть

```
window.onload=function(){
    var originAirport = $( "#origin" ),
        destinationAirport = $( "#destination");

    function init() {
        lookupAirports().then(function( data ) {
            originAirport.add( destinationAirport )
                .autocomplete({
                    source: data.airports,
                    minLength: 2
                });
        });
    }

    function lookupAirports() {
        return $.getJSON( "/api/v1/airports.json" )
    }

    init();
};
```

есть json

```
   {
        "airports": [
            { "name": "Aalborg, Denmark", "iata": "AAL" },
            { "name": "Aalesund, Norway", "iata": "AES" },
            { "name": "Zugapa, Indonesia", "iata": "UGU" },
            { "name": "Zurich, Switzerland", "iata": "ZRH" }
        ]
    }
```

JS требует наличие в json полей label и value,
как сделать что-бы вместо label был name, а вместо value был iata?

Сделал так:

```
function init() {
        lookupAirports().then(function( data ) {
            originAirport.add( destinationAirport )
                .autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        response($.map(data.airports, function(airport) {
                            return {
                                label: airport.name + " " + "(" + airport.iata + ")",
                                value: airport.iata
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    minLength: 2
                });
        });
    }
```

В все нормально находит аэропорты, но постоянно показывает весь список аэропортов, а хотелось бы отсеивать аэропорты которые не попадают под введенное значение, то есть если я в поле ввел AAL, оно должно показать только те аэропорты которые содержать в названии AAL(Aalborg и Aalesund), если я введу AALE(то должно оставить только Aalesund, а остальные аэропорты должны пропасть) а мне при таком воде показывает абсолютно все аэропорты из JSON

HTML

```
<div class="seccio" id="schedule">
  <div class="activebox" id="schedule-panel">
    <div class="activebox-header">
      <div class="cols2">
        <div class="col1">
          Schedule
        </div>
        <div class="col2 info">
          Schedules for next 25 days only
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="activebox-content">
      <div class="cols2">
        <div class="col1">
          <div class="form-element">
            <input type="text" name="origin" id="origin" placeholder="Origin" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-element">
            <input type="text" name="departure" id="departure" placeholder="02/19/2016" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <div class="form-element">
            <input type="text" name="destination" id="destination" placeholder="Destination" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-element">
            <input type="text" name="arrival" id="arrival" placeholder="02/19/2016" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <div class="form-element">
            <input type="submit" name="schedule-submit" value="Get Schedule" id="schedule-submit" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: полный код с html и желательно вставить кодом сюда или на кодепен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр, передаваемый в [`response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - это уже отфильтрованный список, который будет показываться пользователю. Так как сейчас передается полный список, то и показывается он весь.

Для фильтрации можно использовать метод [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), строка, которую ввел пользователь, передается в объекте `request`, в поле `term`.

Таким образом свойство `source` можно заполнить так:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    var filtered = data.airports.filter(function(airport){
        return airport.name.indexOf(request.term) == 0;//Название начинается с введенных символов, 

        //для более общего решения, не зависимого от регистра ввода можно использовать функции toLowerCase
        //return airport.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) == 0;

        // для поиска по всему названию
        //return airport.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    })
    response(filtered.map(function(airport) {
        return {
            label: airport.name + " " + "(" + airport.iata + ")",
            value: airport.iata
        }
   }))
},
```

Comment: что-то не то, вообще не находит аэропорты, но в какую сторону копать я в принципе понял, спасибо

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко, если именно _не находит_  - проверяйте условие которое выполняется, если ошибка в консоли - нужно смотреть ошибку. Сейчас (не за комментированная часть) ищется именно названия которые начинаются с введенной строки, То есть найдется: a -> ala, ale, но не Ala, Ale

Comment: Да действительно, но мне нужны любые подходящие совпадения, даже если То есть js -> JS, js, jS, Js, blabla_JS, blabla_JS_blabla и т.д. я прошу прощения если пишу какую-то чушь, для меня это сложно так как я JS только начинаю осваивать

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко, почитайте комментарий к строке c `return`

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко, добавил различные варианты `return` c комментариями, используйте тот который нужен

Comment: @ Grundy Спасибо большое, то что нужно

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста еще как мне сделать что бы поиск происходил не только по name, но еще и по iata, есть ` { "name": "Zugapa, Indonesia", "iata": "UGU" }` что бы я мог найти этот аэропорт не только  вводя **Zugapa** , но еще если введу **UGU** мне то же бы высветило **Zugapa, Indonesia**

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36006/discussion-between-grundy-and--).